# Photography eCommerce platform

Tags: looking-for-a-script, ecommerce, shopping-cart, photo-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

Anyone have a recommendation for a platform or plugin (free or commercial) to allow the sale of photographic downloads and prints?

I'm not really interested in a hosted solution unless that solution is a stand-out.

Answer (score 2):

The application Gallery2 is FOSS and allows for this:

http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2:Modules:checkout

I have not tried Gallery 3 but Gallery 2 will let you pay with PayPal, Google Checkout and other ways.